# Zotero citation, Undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex, citing, compilation-error, zotero, visual-studio-code

After I installed the `Zotero` connector, I tried to cite through it, following every single step. I don't think there are issues with my citation procedure.

```
\chapter{Introduction}
%
Poly- and perfluoroalkyl substances (PFASs) are a group of highly fluorinated manmade compound that contain one or more carbon atoms on which at least one hydrogen
atoms are replaced by fluorine\autocite{buckPerfluoroalkylPolyfluoroalkylSubstances2011}.
```

And only to find out an error msg
[image: Error msg]
Undefined control sequence.

Meanwhile, after compile, it didn't show the correct formart, just show the key of citation, and it will not connect with the actual citation.

The bib is showing down below:

```
@article{buckPerfluoroalkylPolyfluoroalkylSubstances2011,
  title = {Perfluoroalkyl and Polyfluoroalkyl Substances in the Environment: {{Terminology}}, Classification, and Origins},
  shorttitle = {Perfluoroalkyl and Polyfluoroalkyl Substances in the Environment},
  author = {Buck, Robert C and Franklin, James and Berger, Urs and Conder, Jason M and Cousins, Ian T and family=Voogt, given=Pim, prefix=de, useprefix=true and Jensen, Allan Astrup and Kannan, Kurunthachalam and Mabury, Scott A and family=Leeuwen, given=Stefan PJ, prefix=van, useprefix=true},
  date = {2011},
  journaltitle = {Integrated Environmental Assessment and Management},
  volume = {7},
  number = {4},
  pages = {513--541},
  issn = {1551-3793},
  doi = {10.1002/ieam.258},
  url = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ieam.258},
  urldate = {2023-04-19},
  abstract = {The primary aim of this article is to provide an overview of perfluoroalkyl and polyfluoroalkyl substances (PFASs) detected in the environment, wildlife, and humans, and recommend clear, specific, and descriptive terminology, names, and acronyms for PFASs. The overarching objective is to unify and harmonize communication on PFASs by offering terminology for use by the global scientific, regulatory, and industrial communities. A particular emphasis is placed on long-chain perfluoroalkyl acids, substances related to the long-chain perfluoroalkyl acids, and substances intended as alternatives to the use of the long-chain perfluoroalkyl acids or their precursors. First, we define PFASs, classify them into various families, and recommend a pragmatic set of common names and acronyms for both the families and their individual members. Terminology related to fluorinated polymers is an important aspect of our classification. Second, we provide a brief description of the 2 main production processes, electrochemical fluorination and telomerization, used for introducing perfluoroalkyl moieties into organic compounds, and we specify the types of byproducts (isomers and homologues) likely to arise in these processes. Third, we show how the principal families of PFASs are interrelated as industrial, environmental, or metabolic precursors or transformation products of one another. We pay particular attention to those PFASs that have the potential to be converted, by abiotic or biotic environmental processes or by human metabolism, into long-chain perfluoroalkyl carboxylic or sulfonic acids, which are currently the focus of regulatory action. The Supplemental Data lists 42 families and subfamilies of PFASs and 268 selected individual compounds, providing recommended names and acronyms, and structural formulas, as well as Chemical Abstracts Service registry numbers. Integr Environ Assess Manag 2011;7:513–541. © 2011 SETAC},
  langid = {english},
  keywords = {Acronyms,Perfluoroalkyl,PFAS,Polyfluoroalkyl,Terminology},
  file = {C\:\\Users\\ZJLab\\Zotero\\storage\\XK9J653E\\Buck et al. - 2011 - Perfluoroalkyl and polyfluoroalkyl substances in t.pdf;C\:\\Users\\ZJLab\\Zotero\\storage\\T8RCJ8K9\\ieam.html}
}
```

Comment: The entry shown in the question does not cause any errors for me when I cite it in a small example document. Your first step should be to find out more about the error. The screenshot shows a shortened digest of the actual massage produced by your editor. Open the `.log` file and copy the complete error message. It will clearly state which command is undefined and it will also show the context in which the error appeared (not just line numbers). Paste the full message to your question, then we can try to help you. Even better would be to post an example document that reproduces the error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The screenshot you posted does not actually mention *which* "undefined control sequence" was encountered. Please provide the missing piece of information.

Comment: You have an unknow (undefined) command (control sequence) in line 143 of some file.  With what you have shown, it could be caused by  `\chapter` (e..g, you ot  a `book`-like document  class) or the  `\autocite`  (e.g., you have not load `biblatex`). With what you have not shown, who know! Reduce you document to a MWEB: a minimal (few lines of code) but **working** (compilable as is, o producing as is only that error) example with bibliography (ony the cites and references really needed to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Any news here? As I mentioned above in a "usual setting" the posted entry does not cause an error and the error message is usually longer and more informative (it mentions the undefined control sequence explicitly and the context in which it is used). We cannot help you properly if we don't get to see code that reproduces the error and the full error message.

Comment: @guokelsey, please describe the process, how you exported data from Zotero. And please provide a short Latex code, starting at `\documentclass`, ending at `\end{document}`with a citation of your faulty reference. Thank you